# Insert text into Excel cell when any one of the cell value text is "Not Executed" in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The below Code is working perfectly when all the range is PASS. But i want any one of the range Example : `G5 is "Not Executed"` then i want to insert as `SQL Error`.

```
   Sub Test()

     If Worksheets("Before Conversion German Count").Range("G4:G80").Text = "PASS" Then
            Worksheets("INDEX").Range("F30") = "Completed"
         Worksheets("INDEX").Range("F30").Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 ElseIf Worksheets("Before Conversion German Count").Range("G4:G80").Text = "Not Executed" Then
          Worksheets("INDEX").Range("F30") = "SQL Error"
         Worksheets("INDEX").Range("F30").Interior.ColorIndex = 44
  Else: Worksheets("INDEX").Range("F30") = "Validation failed"
       Worksheets("INDEX").Range("F30").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
  End If

  End Sub
```

*Can any one help me?*

Comment: You  need to loop over each cell in the input range **G4:G80** and test within that loop.

Comment: If i use the loop then each time results will change right?

Comment: At the moment it looks at cell `G4` and ignores `G5:G80`.  Also, if you give the cell a custom number format of `;;;"ANY TEXT"` it will never fire - the cell contains the value "PASS", but displays the text "ANY TEXT" - always look at the `value` of the cell and not the `text`.

Comment: If you want to check if all the cells in G4:G80 contain "PASS" you could use COUNTIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments let's use COUNTIF

```
Sub Result()
Const PASS = "PASS"
Const NOT_EXECUTED = "Not Executed"
Dim rg As Range

    Set rg = Worksheets("Before Conversion German Count").Range("G4:G80")

    With Worksheets("INDEX").Range("F30")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rg, PASS) = rg.Rows.Count Then
            .Value = "Completed"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rg, NOT_EXECUTED) = rg.Rows.Count Then
            .Value = "SQL Error"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        Else
            .Value = "Validation failed"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you need:

```
With Worksheets("INDEX").Range("F30")
    If Not (Worksheets("Before Conversion German Count").Range("G4:G80").Find("Not executed") Is Nothing) Then
        .Value = "SQL Error"
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    ElseIf (Worksheets("Before Conversion German Count").Range("G4:G80").Find("PASS") Is Nothing) Then
        .Value = "Validation failed"
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
        .Value = "Completed"
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 43
    End If
End With
```

This starts a `With` that points at the output cell.

It then performs a `FIND` on the range so if it can see 1 instance of *Not Executed* then you get the **"SQL Error"** output.

Then it looks for *PASS* and if none are found then output is **"Validation failed"**.

Otherwise, the output is **"Completed"**.

Then it closes off the `WITH`

I think this logic follows your intention but you can tweak it as you wish.